# How do I center controls without resizing them? (.net Winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I have a fairly simple user control that represents a basic login control.  So it has a couple labels, text boxes, and a button.  I would like this user control to fill its container, so I have set its dock mode to fill.  So far easy enough.

Now, I would like all the controls in my user control to be centered based on whatever size my user control is when rendered.  I can't think of a anchor / dock combination that will do the trick.

The user control has a ReSize event.  So I know I can calculate and move the controls based on my User control's size during that event.  But I was hoping this issue was common enough to be handled through the designer if I desired.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering controls within a form in .NET (Winforms)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491399/centering-controls-within-a-form-in-net-winforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the TableLayoutPanel control and use it in conjunction with the docking and anchor properties.  You should be able to control the layout fairly precisely that way.

Comment: Of course.  I've been out of Winforms programming for a bit and I missed this one in the docs.  Spoiled by css I guess, I didn't look hard enough.  Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

It is actually all pretty simple.  You just have to turn off all anchor properties, and set dock to none.