# How to keep form centered to the middle of the screen after resize

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, centering

I have a form that is centered according to the screen position that I resize by fontsize when loading. After resizing the location remains the same as it was before resizing so the form is no longer in the center, like I would like.

Let me draw you a sketch:
[image]

I've tried calling

```
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();
```

again after resizing (this is, I believe, the part of the code that centers the form in the beginning). It didn't work. I've also found some similar issues like this:
 ["Keeping winform control centered after window resize
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593411/keeping-winform-control-centered-after-window-resize?noredirect=1&lq=1) but they always only deal with centring a control, not the form itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add method for `ResizeEnd` event. In method, when `ResizeEnd` is fired, get current screen size (on multiple monitors, screen that contains current form) and then calculate form's position. Take a look at this example

```
private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Screen myScreen = Screen.FromControl(this);
    Rectangle area = myScreen.WorkingArea;

    this.Top = (area.Height - this.Height) / 2;
    this.Left = (area.Width - this.Width) / 2;
}
```