# trying to center a Picturebox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, coordinates, picturebox

I'm placing some pictureboxes with coordinates

`pictureBox.Location = new Point(x, y);`

if i choose the coordinates `75,40`  the picturebox appears in that coordinates but in the left corner, I want the picturebox appears in `75,40` centered. like this:
[image]

Comment: @Venson there's no picturebox in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore your right sir!

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491399/c-centering-controls-within-a-form-in-net-winforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is simple, you just have to subtract the position that you want by the size of the pictureBox and divide it by 2.

So, instead of this

pictureBox.Location = new Point(x, y);

You want this

```
pictureBox.Location = new Point(x - pictureBox.Size.Width/2, y - pictureBox.Size.Height/2);
```

Comment: No problem, by the way, just click in the check mark, on the left of my answer if it helped you.