# Visual C# - how to align items in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

*This is my first C# program so please, forgive me.*

I'm using winforms (WPF seemed more alien) and I'd like to center (or align somehow) the items on a form, but I don't know how.

I tried the `Format` menu, but everything is greyed out and, in code view, nothing like HorizontalAlign property was in the suggestions.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Visual Studio should allow aligning from top menu. Make sure you are not running application when aligning. Also select multiple items with a control button pressed down and then align controls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Centering controls within a form in .NET (Winforms)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491399/c-centering-controls-within-a-form-in-net-winforms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set anchor of an item to left and right to keep it centered horizontally and top+bottom to center the item vertically. However if you have few items you want to center that's not doable really, unless you'll put them in a grouping control like `Panel` for example.

Edit: I assumed we're talking about keeping items centered at runtime, because for adjusting a control to the center position there's a button on your toolbar, you know..

Answer (score 1):

There should be an [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute, is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I just want to place them in the middle for example. :)

Comment: Then you have to replace them in the resize event i guess there's no other way...

Comment: I don't think this was what I was looking for, but thanks for the help. This Dock thing looks neat. :)