# How to center panel for all resolutions

Tags: c#, panel

I am a beginner. I would like to ask how can I center Panel for all resolutions. I have panel which includes other panels and its called ParentPanel. I have tryed to add to designer this stuff

```
ParentPanel.Location = new Point(
this.ClientSize.Width / 2 - ParentPanel.Size.Width / 2,
this.ClientSize.Height / 2 - ParentPanel.Size.Height / 2);
ParentPanel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
```

but it said : the type of namescape "point" could not be found, so I used help and it changed `New point` to `New System.Drawing.Point` but still it didnt work :/

My Form is fullscreen and its not sizebale so, WindowsState is Maximazed and StartPosition is CenterScreen.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: See this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491399/c-centering-controls-within-a-form-in-net-winforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not place this code in designer because designer's code is called from constructor, and form is not visible at that moment yet.

Instead, handle `SizeChanged` event of your `Form` (or override `OnSizeChanged` method), and set position of `ParentPanel` there.

Comment: I forgot to say that I have form which starts Fullscreen and its not sizebale. WindowsState is Maximazed and StartPosition is CenterScreen.

Comment: @Kuri, anyway - constructor is not a right place to calculate width of maximized form because form is not visible at that moment and form width is actually the value you set in designer, not the value it will be when maximized form will become visible. Handle `VisibleChanged` or override `protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)` (as it will be called on form become visible too) and place your code there.

Answer (score 0):

Your maths isn't quite right. Try this:

```
ParentPanel.Location = new Point(
    (this.ClientSize.Width - ParentPanel.Size.Width) / 2,
    (this.ClientSize.Height - ParentPanel.Size.Height) / 2);
ParentPanel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
```

Comment: Thank you but I will still get the error "namespace point could not be found"

Comment: I thought we had already established that you shouldn't be putting this code in the designer file? Ideally handle the form's Loading event and put the code in there (you won't get the namespace error). Or, at a push, put it in the form's constructor AFTER the call to InitializeComponent().

Comment: But my Math is not bad, when I tryed your and my code, there is no different :)