# Change the width of label when form get resized

Tags: c#

I want to change the width of the label as user resize the form.

This is the code that I tried:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int lb;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lb = this.Width - label1.Width;
        }

        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Width = lbl() ;
        }

        private int lbl()
        {
            return this.Width / 2 - lb;
        }
   }
```

Comment: You could use the SizeChanged Event available by the Form class

Comment: You can just anchor the label to the form What does your current code do that is incorrect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Centering controls within a form in .NET (Winforms)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491399/centering-controls-within-a-form-in-net-winforms)

Comment: It is just a simple bug, it should be `return this.Width - lb;`  Instead, just set the AutoSize property to False and turn on the right Anchor so this works without writing any code.

Comment: its just changing the location not the size, i want to change the size of label as user resizing the form, to fit all the control properly

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Anchor** property to link your label with form borders.

UPDATE:
You can also use **TableLayoutPanel** to dynamically lays out its contents: http://bit.ly/1KWypIX

Comment: its just changing the location not the width of the label, i want to change the width

Comment: The Anchor property can change the width and/or the location of your component: you need to defined where the anchor is linked. If you need 1/2 resizing, you can use a TableLayoutPanel: http://bit.ly/1KWypIX

Comment: "its not working" actually means "I turned off the left anchor".