# Center horizontally and vertically ignores windowstate maximized

Tags: c#, controls, alignment, windowstate

As I said in the title center horizontally and verticaly buttons aligns my controls in Visual Studio C# according to form size which I randomly put to see my for clearly ( 751; 469 ) to be exact, it centers the controlls according to that size but my form starts as maximized window as it should be. How can I align the controls as the window maximized?

Comment: are u using winforms ?

Comment: @Kapoor yea i am using winforms

Comment: does this serve yr purpose ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491399/centering-controls-within-a-form-in-net-winforms

Comment: Well it worked when i changed anchor of them to none, not exactly like in that link but still helped. thank you. if you can put it as answer so i can confrim it.

Comment: Thanks . Glad to know it helped. As an answer I'll add another approach too, so you can explore that option as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most simple will be to change the anchoring, as mentioned here [Centering controls within a form in .NET (Winforms)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491399/centering-controls-within-a-form-in-net-winforms)

Or

we can also explore `TableLayoutPanel`. This is what comes to my mind -

1. On the main form Control  Add a `TableLayoutPanel` with 3 `Column` and 3 `Row`, To make a 3x3 matrix. Set its `Dock`style  to `Fill`
2. you can configure the width of column & rows in %age so the middle cell of this matrix takes the maximum area, something like this [image]

Something like this [image]

3. Since only one control can be added in a cell, I'll add a panel in the center cell (with `Dock` style set to `Fill`), & then I'll add controls to this panel. The anchoring of these controls is set to none.

this is how it looks at design time

[image]

And it scales pretty well when you maximize the window at runtime, like this [image]

Hope adding table makes it an easy design. Incase of any issues please write me a comment.