# Align a control based on its center

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a desktop application in C # Winforms where I implement a notification system that shows the amount of accumulated notifications.

> My problem is that the label on the bell does not line up in the center

To give me to understand, I want to center the label as SO does with its reputation system

[image]

And for this he has used this code which the SO: [Centering controls within a form in .NET (Winforms)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491399/centering-controls-within-a-form-in-net-winforms)

```
this.CountLabel.Left = ((this.NotificationsBell.ClientSize.Width - this.CountLabel.Width) / 2);
```

But instead of centering my label, this is the result

[image]

> So, how can I align my label from its center?

Note: NotificationsBell is the PictureBox with the image of the bell and CountLabel is the label with the number 100 and blue background

Comment: You need to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently, the relationship between controls (Label and NotificationsBell) is unclear.

Comment: Suggest simply adding a container (e.g. panel) for everything related to this icon, then add the bell and label to that panel and set horizontal alignment of both to center

Comment: Did you try *inspecting* SO's label to see what is used there? Hint: there's `<a><svg/><span>+100</span></a>` then just look the classes used and properties related

Comment: You forget to add `Left` of the bell to the result.

Comment: @LordWilmore 
I have thought of a container panel, but if the width of the label exceeds the size of the panel, then it is cut with the limits of that panel

Comment: @RezaAghaei No, because the bell is in a fixed position and the label is the one who must line up centered on the bell

Comment: Probably you didn't get what I mean. See the answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align center of `control1` to center of `control2` vertically, when both of them are hosted in the same parent, you can use following code:

```
control1.Left = control2.Left + (control2.Width - control1.Width) / 2;
```

Comment: I can not believe that a single line did the work ;-), thank you very much

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán well, you only forgot to add the left X position to your control.