# How can I reset a PictureBox to the center of the Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

After moving my PictureBox around with the arrows, how would I go about using the center button to reset my PictureBox back the the center of the Form?

[image: Overview of form]

Comment: Do you want the car to *jump* or *move smoothly* to the center?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Centering controls within a form in .NET (Winforms)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491399/centering-controls-within-a-form-in-net-winforms)

Comment: Move smoothly if possible but jumping is also acceptable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can put this code in the centre button click.

```
pictureBox.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - pictureBox.Width) / 2 ;
pictureBox.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - pictureBox.Height) / 2;
```

Or you can use `pictureBox.CenterToParent();`, it will position the control within the centre of the parent.